# How to detect overflow flag?

Tags: assembly, binary, flags

In the following question, i wonder why OVERFLOW flag is set to 1.
I know that overflow can only happen when adding two numbers of the same sign and
getting a different sign.
Is this is a mistake in the solution of the book or what?

[image]

Comment: But when signs are different it is impossible to generate overflow! Can you explain your answer?

Comment: Adding 1 to -1 is not a situation in which you have overflow. Carry yes, but not overflow.

Comment: So another mistake in the book solutions>>>Thanks for your response.

Comment: the carry flag is a.k.a as an unsigned overflow.  A signed overflow is different.  Carry out unsigned overflow, signed overflow is if the carry in and carry out of the msbit differ.

Comment: if you want to use the assembly flag then...have some assembly and specify the processor please.

Comment: in order to answer your question you need to specify what the book you are reading defines overflow as.  as far as a signed overflow goes the carry in and carry out of the msbit are both a 1 so this is not a signed overflow -1 + 1 = 0 which can be properly represented with the number of bits provided so no signed overflow.  Unsigned, 0xFF + 1 = 0x00 plus an overflow (because 0x100 cant be represented with 8 bits)

Answer (score 0):

Those look like 8-bit, unsigned numbers.  The result is 9 bits, which would overflow an 8-bit register (hard to find, these days).  If these were signed numbers, they would, indeed have different signs (-1 and 1).  However, the image shows a nine-bit sum, not simply 0 (or even 00000000). So those are unsigned 8-bit or there's an error in "the book".  Notice the half-carry bit is set.  This suggests 1/2 of a 16-bit register is being used.  That happens all the time.

The statement about the signs being different making an overflow impossible -- is just restating the simple relationship about adding 2 numbers of the same bit-size, one of which is positive, the other negative.  The largest 8-bit positive number is 127.  The largest negative 8-bit number is -128.  It's relatively easy to do the math.  Start with 127, and add every possible negative number... 127+-1=126, 127+-2=125, 127+-3=124,  ... 127+-126=1, 127+-127=0, 127+-128=-1.  None of the sums is either greater than 127 or less than -128, so no overflow occurs.  You can finish the proof by adding every positive number to -128.